# Is it possible to call an Non-Standard/Custom Ant Task from inside a script?

Tags: ant, ibm-mq

I'm fairly new to ant.
I'm currently working with the IBM MQ product.
As part of this product there are some ant executions that make use of their IBMs own defined Ant Tasks (eg below 'fte:filecopy')

```
<project xmlns:fte="antlib:com.ibm.wmqfte.ant.taskdefs" name="transfer" default="orchestrate_transfers">
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
...
  <target name="copy">
    <fte:filecopy src="X@Y" dst="X@Y" outcome="await" jobname="test_job" rcproperty="result">
      <fte:filespec srcfilespec="/from/here" dstfile="/to/here" overwrite="true" recurse="false"/>
      <fte:metadata>
        <fte:entry name="mykey" value="myvalue"/>
      </fte:metadata>
    </fte:filecopy>    
  </target>
...
```

I need to execute this and tasks like it, but with a bit of controlling logic that assigns a variable number of metadata entries. I could potentially do this with javascript.

Now, I know I can execute/perform tasks from javascript (eg, The below tasks are equivalent, but one is implemented natively and the other via javascript) but `project.createTask("filecopy")` creates a null object.

```
<project name="demo">
  <target name="test_task">
      <echo message="Hello World"/>
  </target>

  <target name="test_script">
    <script language="script">
      var echo = project.createTask("echo")
      echo.setMessage("Hello World")
      echo.perform()
    </script>
  </target>
</project>
```

Does anyone know how you would normally call a custom task from inside the script?

Comment: You can have your own custom Ant tasks and MFT will execute that as well. But having mix of Ant and JavaScript tasks, don't think that will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm having to extend the product quite a lot to deal with some missing features. My requirement is to create a service pipeline so that all services follow the same flow, and their differences are driven by parameters. Whilst I can create Transfers following the same template but driven by properties, what I can't do is create the outbound file with a derived name from the sourcefile (not a FileTransfer feature). 
As such I'm essentially having to implement it in javascript.